# [ONNXRuntime for android]. What am I have to do solve this problem? AssignNodesToEpsFromHashesImpl Failed to find kernel def hash

Tags: android, onnx, onnxruntime

I got an error like below to use ONNXRuntime on Androidproject.

[image: the third line makes error. it cannot make a session succefully]
[error message]
AssignNodesToEpsFromHashesImpl Failed to find kernel def hash (8090321298879394920) in kernel registries for MaxPool(8) node with name 'layer3/pool_3/MaxPool'.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the link here: https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/reference/operators/mobile_package_op_type_support_1.10.html to check if the opset version used for generating the onnx model supports the layers you are using in your model. If not regenerate the onnx file with a supported opset version as per the list.

You could also otherwise try using the unofficial onnxruntime package available here: https://github.com/gwang-msft/unofficial_onnxruntime_mobile_releases which is most likely expected to work for this layer without dealing with issues related with opset version.